# How to find optimal points through a series of circles?

Tags: linear-algebra, circles

So if you have n circles with radius and center. Let's call these circles C_1, C_2, ..., C_n.
Then how could I find the series of points that is the shortest path from the perimeter on C_1, to the perimeter on C_2, and so on until C_n.
[Here n=4 so how could I finde the points G,H,K,I such that |f|+|g|+|h| is a short as possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGv1C.png)

Comment: How did you create that image? Is it a real solution or is it just for illustration?

Comment: What if your circles form a non-convex figure?

Answer (score 0):

In your figure you have four points $G(x_1,y_1)$, $H(x_2,y_2)$, $I(x_3,y_3)$ and $K(x_4,y_4)$ and four circles given by equations $$f_i(x,y)=(x-a_i)^2+(y-b_i)^2=r_i^2$$
you want to minimize the function
$$g(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4)=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2+(x_3-x_4)^2+(y_3-y_4)^2$$
(which is the sum of the squared distances of the four points) subject to the constraints
$$\begin{cases}
f_1(x_1,y_1)=r_1^2   \\
f_2(x_2,y_2)=r_2^2   \\
f_3(x_3,y_3)=r_3^2   \\
f_4(x_4,y_4)=r_4^2
\end{cases}$$

this can be done using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). You can easily generalize to $n$ points.